# SQL join with 3 tables based on a particular field

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table DM:**
columns : msgid(Primary Key),msggrp
          12345,ABC 
**Table DT:**
columns: msgid(PK),taskid
         12345,45678
**Table TLC:**
id,stateid,deliverymsgid(references msgid from DT table),deliverytaskid
(references tasked from DT table)
32433,325,12345,45678

I need to find stateid from (TLC table) for a particular msgid:

I wrote a query which does that  using :

```
select stateid from tlc
where tasked in
    (select tasked from DT
    where messageid in ('12345')
and stateid in 325
```

this query works but I need to write query with where clause with
where condition as msggroup column (DM Table)

where msgrp in ('msggrp')  in sql server

Could you guys please help me out.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: is DM and DT table connected anyhow?

Comment: @Viplock,yes by msgid

Answer (score 1):

You can use join join like this.

```
   select stateid from tlc
   join DT on tlc.deliverymsgid= DT.msgid
   join DM on DT.msgid=DM.msgid
   where DM.msggrp ='ABC'
```

But as i think , your database structure is not proper, You shouldn't be having msgid as PK in both the tables. One table should have it as a PK and other table should connect it by FK.

Hope it will help you.